# In Vim, why is temporary Normal Mode (Ctrl-O from Insert Mode) executing commands much slower?

Tags: vim

Usually, when I want to undo changes while editing text in Vim, I have to:

1. Exit Insert mode with `Esc`
2. Press `u` to undo changes
3. Enter into Insert mode with various commands (`i`, `o`, etc...)

Now, I am just a beginner, but I understand that while in Insert mode, you can temporarily escape into Normal mode for one command by using `Ctrl-O`.

Knowing this, when I want to undo changes in text, I figured: why not just escape into temporary Normal mode and press `u` and not have to deal with all the shenanigans of `Esc` and switching between modes?

So I did the following:

1. Escape into temporary Normal mode for one command, using `Ctrl-O`
2. Press `u` to undo changes
3. I am automatically in Insert mode and continue editing.

***It works... except it's VERY, VERY. slow.*** The cursor would be immediately placed at the position after the undo is executed, but the changes in the text aren't displayed until after ~2 seconds. That's a very long time.

I thought it was just my computer running slowly for some reason but I did the old-school way and the undo was executed instantly. Granted, this isn't the case for all commands. When I try to `dd` and delete the whole line, it works just as expected - instantly.

So my question is: why? Is temporary Normal mode not the same as the Normal mode one would enter from pressing `Esc`? Does it have anything to do with buffers, or swap files, or whatever is going on behind the scenes? Is it the way `undo` is implemented in the Vim editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear that Vim is waiting for a possible second keypress, i.e., the motion to the command (e.g., `dw`, which executes normally). Obviously the `u` command doesn't have a motion, but double tapping `uu` does execute the undo quickly, it just then inserts the next u into the document. I suspect this is a quirk of how the 'temporary normal mode' decides when to return to 'insert mode'.

Comment: I'd almost suggest that this is a bug

Comment: It might very well be a bug.

Your answer made sense seemingly... however I tried deleting a single character during the temporary Normal mode using `x`. It worked instantly.

Comment: Haha, gf course! I can't fathom why it would be so much slower. We're talking 2 to 3 seconds waiting. I'm thinking deletion commands are much faster to execute because you're just deleting. For undo, Vim probably has the last changes stashed somewhere (the `.swp` file) and has to access it. Even if this is the case why would the temporary Normal mode slow down the command by such magnitudes? It's almost insane. Anyhow, I don't even know how undo operations are implemented in computers, so my "theory" is bogus.